# Read cookies of client system

Tags: java

How can i read cookies of the client system for Java web application.

My application on server and i want to fetch some information of client system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following in your servlet/jsp to get [cookies](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/products/products/servlet/2.5/docs/servlet-2_5-mr2/javax/servlet/http/Cookie.html)

```
javax.http.servlet.Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
```

> i want to make cookies with some information which user enters and next time i use that information

An example of what you want to do is [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JSP/SettingandReadingCookies.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You get cookies from the client system by using a javascript (on the client) to read the cookie and formulate a web request to send to your server.

Use something like the javascript XMLHTTPRequest function (on the client) to send the request to your server (including the cookie value).